# Sequelize nested associations query

Tags: sequelize.js, sequelize-typescript

I have a model with multiple chained association as follows :

Epci `-> have many ->` Communes `-> have one ->` Departement `-> have one ->` Region

I'm trying to retreive `Epci` rows with their associated `Regions` as a result like :

```
[
    {
        id: 1,
        name: 'EPCI 1',
        regions: [         // [1, 2] is also an acceptable format 
            { id: 1 },
            { id: 2 } 
        ]  
    }
]
```

For the moment, I achieved to get a result like this :

```
    [
        {
            id: 1,
            name: 'EPCI 1',
            communes: [         
                { 
                    id: 1, 
                    departement: {
                        id: 1,
                        region: {
                           id: 1
                        }  
                    } 
                },
                { 
                    id: 2, 
                    departement: {
                        id: 1,
                        region: {
                           id: 1
                        }  
                    } 
                },
                { 
                    id: 3, 
                    departement: {
                        id: 2,
                        region: {
                           id: 2
                        }  
                    } 
                },
            ]  
        }
    ]
```

With this call :

```
Epci.findAll({
    attributes: [
        'id',
        'name',
    ],
    include: [{
        model: Commune,
        attributes: ['id'],
        include: [{
            model: Departement,
            attributes: ['id'],
            include: [{
                model: Region,
                attributes: ['id'],
            }],
        }],
    }],
})
```

Is there a way to retrieve directly the associated (and distinct) `Regions` using the `findAll` function ? Tried to use a `Virtual` column and some kind of aliases, without success...

(I'm trying to avoid runing a query foreach retrieved rows)

<strike>**Current temporary (?) solution (btw using Sequelize TypeScript):**</strike>

The current goal is to retrieve an simple array of Regions and clean the Epci results of the "communes" tree attribute returned by Sequelize.

So, we perform the request and retrieve needed data then transform result with Javascript.

```
Epci.findAll({
    attributes: [
        'id',
        'name',
    ],
    include: [{
        model: Commune,
        attributes: ['id'],
        include: [{
            model: Departement,
            attributes: ['id'],
            include: [{
                model: Region,
                attributes: ['id'],
            }],
        }],
    }],
}).map((row: Epci) => {
    // Retrieve plain object 
    const plain = row.get({ plain: true });

    // Rebuild (retreive, unique) the regions property (declared as Virtual in the Epci model -- important).
    plain.regions = plain.communes.map(commune => {
        return commune.departement.region.id;
    }).filter((id, index, self) => {
        return self.indexOf(id) === index;
    });
    // Remove the communes property.
    delete plain.communes;

    // Rebuild Epci instance with the modified plain object
    const instance = this.repository.build(plain);

    // Then return instance 
    return instance;
});
```

**Accepted and performant solution using Postgresql array functions :**

```
sequelize.query(`
    SELECT 
        E.id,
        E.name,
        ARRAY_AGG(DISTINCT R.id) as "regions"
    FROM layer_epci E
    LEFT JOIN layer_commune C ON C.epci_id = E.id
    LEFT JOIN layer_departement D ON C.departement_id= D.id
    LEFT JOIN layer_region R ON D.region_id = R.id
    GROUP BY E.id
`, {
   model: Epci,
   mapToModel: true
}).map((row: Epci) => {
    // Do some crazy stuff with Epci models.
    return epci;
});
```

Comment: This is really a good question!!! But I believe you should do it the way you are doing. However, if you want to "reduce" the volume of data returned, you can remove the fields that you do not want to see on return, using `attributes: { exclude: ['baz'] }`. You can further simplify the process by using [JOIN TABLE](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/class/lib/associations/belongs-to-many.js~BelongsToMany.html) in the sequelize, I think this is the case of the relationship between COMMUNES -> DEPARTEMENT -> REGION, am I right?

Comment: @WagnerdeAndradePerin Nope, `Commune` have one `Departement`, `Departement` have one `Region` and `Epci` have many `Communes`. There is no many2many relation here. I'll post the current solution I'm using because it implies to clean returned instances and this process isn't really "simple".

Comment: Oh, sorry. Have you ever tried to write and run your own querys? You can use [this](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/raw-queries.html).

Comment: Nice solution, works like a charm, plus, there is no need to add a Virtual column in the `Epci` model. Thx for idea, I post the solution.

Comment: Glad to have helped! =]